# Combine rows from different tables based on common columns pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have 3 tables/df. All have same column names. Bascially they are df for data from different months

October  (df1 name)

```
Sales_value    Sales_units   Unique_Customer_id  Countries  Month 
   1000            10             4                  1       Oct
     20          2                4                 3        Oct
```

November  (df2 name)

```
Sales_value    Sales_units   Unique_Customer_id   Countries   Month
   2000          1000             40                 14        Nov
   112             200            30                 10         Nov
```

December (df3 name)

```
Sales_value    Sales_units   Unique_Customer_id   Countries  Month 
   20009090       4809509       4500                 30       Dec
```

etc. This is dummy data. Each table has thousands of rows in reality. How to combine all these 3 tables such that columns come only once and all rows are displayed such that rows from October df come first, followed by November df rows followed by December df rows. When i use joins I am getting column names repeated.

Expected output:

```
Sales_value    Sales_units   Unique_Customer_id   Countries     Month 
 1000            10             4                   1            Oct
 20              2              4                   3           Oct     
2000             1000          40                   14           Nov
  112             200          30                   10         Nov    
20009090       4809509       4500                   30           Dec
```

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html

Comment: `pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concat combines rows from different tables based on common columns

```
  pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])
```